# PHP Fatal Error –Class 'Html' not found

Tags: php, yii

I am making a demo website http://www.yiichina.com/doc/guide/2.0/start-forms . I am seeing fatal errors.

PHP code:

```html
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<p>You have entered the following information:</p>
<ul>
    <li><lable>Name</lable>:<?=Html::encode($model->name) ?></li>
    <li><lable>Email</lable>:<?=Html::encode($model->email) ?></li>
</ul>
```

Fatal error:

```
<--
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'Html' not found
1. in C:\Apache24\htdocs\yii\basic\views\site\entry-confirm.php at line 6
123456789

2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()
Yii Framework
2016-03-06, 04:43:36

Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2f PHP/5.6.18
Yii Framework/2.0.7
-->
```

Comment: Replace <? with <?php

Comment: <lable> is not correct. use <label> instead.

Comment: Do you have yii2 framework installed in the right place? Can you find it in the ./vendor directory? Was composer update running successfully?